# Add css in two steps with react?

Tags: reactjs

A common case when doing css-transitions is that you first need to set some initial values and then transition to other values. In my case, I need to change a box to position absolute and then I want to transition it to fullscreen. This is what I tried:

```js
componentDidMount (props) {
  this.flky = new Flickity('.carousel', flickityOptions)

  this.flky.on('staticClick', () => {
    this.setState({ zoom: 'transition' }, () => {
      this.setState({ zoom: 'full' })
    })
  })
}

setStyle () {
  const container = this.refs.container
  if (this.state.zoom === 'transition') {
    return {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: container.offsetTop + 'px',
      left: container.offsetLeft + 'px',
      width: container.offsetWidth + 'px',
      height: container.offsetHeight + 'px',
      transition: 'all .5s'
    }
  } else if (this.state.zoom === 'full') {
    return {
      background: 'white',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      transition: 'all .5s'
    }
  }
}

<div ref='container' style={this.setStyle()} />
```

The problem seems to be that the initial css is not applied before the secondary is applied, so the div goes straight to fullscreen. I'm trying to achieve this using the `setState` callback but it does not work.

This works with a 0ms delay, for some reason.

```js
this.flky.on('staticClick', () => {
  this.setState({ zoom: 'transition' }, () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ zoom: 'full' }, () => {
          this.flky.resize()
      }, 0)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: it works if I add a delay on 0 seconds for some reason, but that is usually not a good practice, is there some callback that I could use or somehting?

Comment: The initial css **is** applied. Your problem that you need to have a 0.5sec delay between first and second `setState` (but they goes faster). I think this way has disadvantage in general. Maybe you'll find more usefull to use `keyframes` in css - to do all transitions only via css.

Comment: thankyou, however, that's not how css works. the transitions starts from when the new css is applied, so it can't be overwritten in that sense. I updated the question with a 0ms delay.

Comment: But it owerwrites!)) not because of css, but because react override the hole element when rerender it with new state. I believe you'll catch it if set long durations. i.e. 10sec for transition and 5sec for setTimeout - check what you'll see?

Comment: it works with 0 sec, i don't need any time.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the state has been set you then overwrite it with another state. Instead of setting the css in the callback of setState you would want to set it as soon as the first is done instead.

I'd just use a react library for animations if I were you. React Motion has an `onRest` callback which you would use for this.

Comment: Can I somehow force a render before I overwrite it?

Comment: The transition will still not be done though and get overwritten. .5s is ALOT longer than `setState`.

Comment: according to the css specs, if the object has a css-property and then get a new css-property the transition happens, I'll update the question to calrify.